# Could I use variable values on different port in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

> SyntaxError : Cannot use import statement outside a module

index.ts

```
let angle_ne = "Northeast";
export {angle_ne};
export let angle_nw = "Northwest";
```

index.js

```
// next 2 line make "SyntaxError : Cannot use import statement outside a module".
// import angle_ne from "./index"
// console.log(angle_ne);

const express    = require('express');
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const dbconfig   = require('./database.js');
const connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
const app = express();

// configuration =========================
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Root');
});

app.get('/address', (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * from address where Faddress like "%SEOUL%"', (error, rows) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    // console.log(angle_ne);
    console.log('Address info from DB : ', rows);
    res.send(rows);
    
  });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Created a page related to Google Map API of Google Maps in Node.js.

index.ts: It consists of maps and API-related coding parts and works on localhost:5173.
The address of the clicked position is stored in a variable and displayed in console.log.

And I made MySQL connect in localhost:3000.
I tried to run API and db on the same port, but it has a problem with not work API or not work DB. So I gave different port.

I want to use the values stored in variables of index.ts in index.js.
Is it possible in its current state? If possible what should I find?
Or it can't import values with export import because the port is different?

I expect to showing "Northeast" in console.
I tried export from index.ts and import to index.js
it make "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module".

I want to create a query using the values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax appears to be inconsistent. You can either use `require()` or the es6 import/export syntax. But not both.

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp